# Use an Outlook message file (msg) as a template

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop, outlook-redemption

I wonder if it's possible with the .net framework or Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook to load an email message (*.msg), do a search and replace and send it from C#.

It's all happening on the server so Outlook cannot be installed.

What I've tried

- the Redemption library but somehow it loses the images inlined in the template and can't figure out to remedy this
- Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

  ```
      Application objOutlook = new Application();
      objOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("c:\temp\..",)
  ```

But it expects as it second parameter an outlook folder, I can't give it a file path where it will save to

I'm thinking to switch to regular txt files instead of C# but maybe someone did this already

**Update 1**

This is the redemption code I tried. The problem is that the formatting and image (of a signature is not preserved)

```
using Interop.Redemption;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Replace(@"mailnonunicode.msg");
            Replace(@"mailunicode.msg");
            Replace(@"mailtemplate.oft");
        }

        static void Replace(string cTestharnessKmailMsg)
        {
            RDOSession rdoSession = new RDOSession();
            RDOMail messageFromMsgFile = rdoSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile(cTestharnessKmailMsg);

            messageFromMsgFile.Body = messageFromMsgFile.Body.Replace("abc",
                                                                      "xyz");
            messageFromMsgFile.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2 / Solution**

If you want to preserve the formatting, you need to work with HTMLBody or RTFBody properties, not with the plain text Body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your existing Redemption code?

If the message needs to be sent, it must be created in one of the Outlook folders - a standalone MSG file cannot be sent.

Comment: I can't have outlook installed on the server so no outlook folders. I think that rules out redemption thus. :(

Comment: The RDO family of objects (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) does not need Outlook, only the MAPi system, which means you can have the standalone version of MAPI installed (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e17e7f31-079a-43a9-bff2-0a110307611e&DisplayLang=en). You can then call RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox to dynamically connect to a mailbox, retrieve the folder where the message will be created (e.g. RDOSession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts), create the message (RDOFolder.Items.Add) import the MSG file (RDOMail.Import), then send it.

Comment: I've added my code to the question. Isn't this the way to make a replacement? I can send you the complete solution if that's helpful.

Comment: If you want to preserve the formatting, you need to work with HTMLBody or RTFBody properties, not with the plain text Body.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, that was the solution